# Normal Subgroups in Relation to Larger Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

This quote is taken from Chapter 3, Section 1 of Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra:

"Keep in mind that the property of being a normal subgroup is an *embedding* property, that is, it depends on the relation of $N$ to $G$, not on the internal structure of $N$ itself (the same group $N$ may be a normal subgroup of $G$ but not be normal in a larger group containing $G$)."

Even if $N$ is a subnormal subgroup of $H$, that is $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $G\trianglelefteq H$, then $N$ is not necessarily normal in $H$, contrary to what one might expect. My question is if $N$ is normal in $G$ and $G$ is a subgroup of $H$, what conditions imply $N$ is also normal in $H$? I came across the concept of a T-group which is a group with the property that normality is transitive, so if $H$ is a T-group, and $G\trianglelefteq H$, then $N\trianglelefteq H$. Are there any other ways for $N$ to be normal in $H$, or can we only consider groups that are subnormal?

Comment: When $N$ is within $H$.

Comment: I've already assumed $N$ is in $H$.  $N$ is normal in $G$, not necessarily in $H$.

Comment: I read the problem wrongly. My fault not yours.

Comment: I don't think you are using subnormal correctly when you say "$N$ is a subnormal subgroup of $H$, that is $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $G\trianglelefteq H$".

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. There are certainly groups $N\leqslant G \leqslant H$ with $N\trianglelefteq G$, $N\trianglelefteq H$ but $G\not\trianglelefteq H$. (Taking $N=1$ is a good start to finding examples.)

Comment: This was my source https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_subgroup. I'm pretty sure I followed the definition correctly, the chain of subgroups starts with $N$ and ends with $H$, and each group in the chain is normal with respect to the following one. Maybe my notation is wrong?

Comment: I'm just curious about when the property of normality in one group is preserved for larger groups. Also I see what you're saying, if $G\not \trianglelefteq H\implies N\not \trianglelefteq H$, then taking the contrapositive implies $N\trianglelefteq H\implies G \trianglelefteq H$ which clearly does not have to hold unless additional assumptions are made.